# get data from database using ajax not working

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

i have this code:connection to database

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "jquery");
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
```

now i already have data indatabase in table called city witch it have only id and desc and this is the code

```
if (isset($_POST['city'])) {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM city";

        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            $results = [];
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $results[] = $row;
            }
            echo json_encode($Results);
        }
        else
        {
            echo "empty";
        }
    }
```

here is the html part:

```
 <select required="required" id="city">
                            <option disabled selected value=''> select a city </option>
                        </select>
```

and here is the function:

```
 function city() {
            $.ajax({
               "url": "divs.php",
               "dataType": "json",
               "method": "post",
               //ifModified: true,
               "data": {
                   "F": ""
               }
            })
            .done(function(data, status) {
                if (status === "success") {
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        var c = data[i]["city"];
                        $('select').append('<option value="'+c+'">'+c+'</option>');
                    }

                }
            })
            .always(function() {

            });
        }
```

so the problem is that there is nothing in select list its always empty, any help? thank u

Comment: `$results` is not the same as `$Results`

Comment: Maybe in your PHP part where we have the variable $results u have a capital $Results that could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have used `$results` but while echoing you are using `$Results` which is a different variable so use,

```
echo json_encode($results);
```

Also, you are telling that `city` has only `id` and `desc` so in JS code use `desc` instead of `city`

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url: 'divs.php',
    data: {city:1},
    success:function(data) {
        var res = JSON.parse(data);
        $(res).each(function(){
            var c = this.city_name; // use city_name here instead of city
            $('select').append('<option value="'+c+'">'+c+'</option>');
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: If this is the only problem than why don't you flag it for closure because of a typo?

Comment: @adamspaul If you know the problem(s) why are you asking the question at all? O.o

Comment: i dont know where is the problem @Andreas im asking to figure out where

Comment: @adamspaul try now.

Answer (score 0):

One small mistake is here:
You are using

```
echo json_encode($Results);
```

instead of

```
echo json_encode($results);
```

In PHP variable names are case sensitive. So, use proper case for all the variables.

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting the response data in HTML `<SELECT>` TAG here is what you can do.

image to table
[image: city table image]

HTML FILE CODE:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <select>

        </select>
    </form> 
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    city();
});

function city(){
     $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
           url: 'divs.php',
           data: {city:1},
           success:function(data){
                var res = JSON.parse(data)

                for(var i in res){
                    var showdata = '<option value="'+res[i].city_name+'">'+res[i].city_name+'</option>';

                    $("select").append(showdata);
                }
           }
        });
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

HERE IS THE PHP CODE

`

```
<?php
    $conn = new mysqli('localhost','root','','demo');

    if($conn->connect_error){
        die ("Connection Failed".$conn->link->error);
    }

    if(isset($_POST['city'])){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM city";

        $result = $conn->query($sql);

        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $results[] = $row;
            }
            echo json_encode($results);
        }
        else
        {
            echo "no city available";
        }
    }
?>
```

`

HERE IS THE OUTPUT IMAGE

[image: OUTPUT RESULT]